# Angular synchronous calls with observables

Tags: angular, synchronization, subscription

I have a situation where I defined a variable `diary: Diary` in my typescript file. When the user clicks a certain save button I have to execute `f1`, a function having the following structure:

```
public f1() {
   if (condition 1) {
      this.service.serviceCall(param).subscribe(res =>
         diary.firstPage.push(res)
      )
   }

   if (condition 2) {
       this.service.serviceCall(param).subscribe(res =>
          diary.secondPage.push(res)
   }

   if (condition 3) { ... }

   ...
}
```

`f1()` is executed before `f2()` which does the following:

```
public f2() {
   this.diaryService.saveDiary(diary).subscribe();
}
```

Since `f1` modifies the `diary` label, I have to make sure that `f2` is executed only after all the subscriptions of `f1` have been completed. How can I do that?

Comment: Any logic that needs to be executed only after the observable is finished should go into the `subscribe(res => {})` block.

Comment: The problem is: where to start? I don't know which subscribe will be the first one in `f1()`. Sometimes only one will be executed, sometimes none, sometimes all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a Promise approach should be easy here, where you wait for all the responses and then finally make a save call:

```
public async f1() {
  try {
    if (condition 1) {
        const res = await this.service.serviceCall(param).toPromise();
        diary.firstPage.push(res)
    }

    if (condition 2) {
        const res = await this.service.serviceCall(param).toPromise();
        diary.secondPage.push(res)
    }

    //at the end
    this.f2();

  } catch() {
    // something heer
  }
}
```

This can also be tackled using maybe `forkJoin`, where you prepare the an array of Observables based on the conditions and finally make the `f2` call in forkJoin subscription. This gives you an advantage of parallel calls.

**ForkJoin**

```
public f1() {
  const allApis: any = {};
  
  if (condition 1) {
    allApis.firstPage = this.service.serviceCall(param);
  }

  if (condition 2) {
      allApis.secondPage = this.service.serviceCall(param);
  }

  //at the end
  forkJoin(allApis).pipe(tap((responses) => {
    Object.entries(responses).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      diary[k].push(v)
    });
  })).subscribe(() => {
    this.f2()
  });
}
```

Comment: Something like this is exactly what I am looking for. I didn't consider using the `forkJoin` only after preparing the array of observables. Thanks!

Comment: @Rexam: It just has a downside of waiting for each service call to finish before doing the next, forkJoin would take care of that. With some additional logic for updating the appropriate array for the responses.